# USB 3.0 not working on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, usb, ultrabook

I've spent a lot of time trying to figure out why my USB 3.0 doesn't work on Ubuntu 13.04, but I was not able to find the answer. So I have decided to post this question here now.

The port on my VAIO T ultrabook is definitely getting power, but no device is recognized when I plug it in.

```
uname -a
3.8.0-25-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 6 20:47:07 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 046d:c05b Logitech, Inc. M-U0004 810-001317 [B110 Optical USB Mouse]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0489:e036 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05ca:18c4 Ricoh Co., Ltd
```

I could post any other outputs here if needed. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Do you have any BIOS/UEFI settings related to the USB ports?

Comment: Can you post the output from the dmesg|tail command just after the usb device is plugged?

Comment: Hey, I had this problem, with my Galaxy Note 3, and solved using a cable usb 2.0 http://goo.gl/7pgV7m

Comment: Have you tried Ubuntu 14.04 yet?

Comment: Check your BIOS settings and make sure those ports are enabled.